# Jasmine and Angularjs - Why $index is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd, jasmine

The script works, but not if I test it.

Jasmine:

```
describe("myApp", function(){

        beforeEach(module("mymod"));

        describe("maincontroller", function(){

            var scope;
            var ctrl;
            var compile;
            var html;
            beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $compile){
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                ctrl = $controller("maincontroller", {$scope:scope});

                compile = $compile;

                html = angular.element('<ul id="listONE"><li class="{{person.isSel}}" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="selPersonToChange($index)">{{person.name +" - "+ person.city}}</li></ul>');
                compile(html)(scope);
                scope.$digest();    

            }));

            it("Is selPersonToChange() working?", function(){
                expect(scope.selPersonToChange(ind)).toEqual(true);
            });
});
```

Comment: yes... but only into the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined '**ind**' anywhere in that JavaScript file. The ng-click should work as $index is defined in the ng-repeat. But your test has declaration of '**ind**'.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving `selPersonToChange` any index to change, it should be

```js
it("Is selPersonToChange() working?", function(){
    var ind = 0;
    scope.selPersonToChange(ind);
    // scope.$digest(); // only needed if it needs to reflect on your DOM
    expect(scope.people[ind].isSel).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: Yep, but I would like to test whether the function return true, not if the persons (people[x]) is selected.